# What is the easiest way to connect from Python to SQLServer?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to **SQLServer ** with python and put **pandas** dataframe on it as table
and execute queries, how can I do this?
For example, I want to be able to determine the primary key for a table from Python and minimize my need for SSMS.
It would be great if this tool helps to log database interactions
I tried with *sqlalchemy*, it's a good tool, but is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

so i created it :)
it's named pySqlServer with github page:https://github.com/sajad-git/pySqlServer

some usage tips:
at first you can use pip install pysqlserver to install it

## Usage

Import PySQL and Table_analyzer:

```py
from pySqlServer import PySQL, Table_analyzer
```

---

---

#### Table_analyzer usage:

A helper class for analyzing Pandas DataFrames to determine optimal SQL datatypes.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
TA = Table_analyzer()
dtype_dict = TA.analyze(df,texts_buffer=0.2)
```

> - for texts_buffer > 1 :  N in nvarchar(N) sets to len_max_length + texts_buffer
> - for 0 < texts_buffer < 1 :  N in nvarchar(N) sets to len_max_length + texts_buffer*len_max_length (extra percentage)

---

---

#### PySQL usage:

- Create a connection

```py
pysql = PySQL()
pysql.create_connection(server='host_ip', database='mydb', username='myuser', password='mypassword', local_sql=False)
```

> your user must have 'db_datareader', 'db_datawriter', 'db_ddlAdmin' permissions to module works perfectly
> set local_sql=True for windows auth in local SQL Server

- at first use (for every tables) you must call create_dtypes()

```py
dtype_dict = {'col1':sql.sqltypes.INTEGER , 'col2':sql.sqltypes.NVARCHAR(100)} # it's suggested to use Table_analyzer to calculate optimal dtype_dict
# dtype_dict = TA.analyze(df,texts_buffer=0.2) 
pysql.create_dtypes(dtype_dict=dtype_dict, table_name='Test_table', schema='Test_schema')
```

- at all next usages you must call load_dtypes and next you can use to_sql method to send data

```py
pysql.load_dtypes(table_name='Test_table', schema='Test_schema')    # created before
pysql.to_sql(df,'Test_table', schema='Test_schema', if_exists='append', text_cutter=True, date_normalizer=True, method='multi', verbos=True)
```

> - you can use primary_key='column_name' to set tables primary_key
> - in next usages it's not allowed to use this
> - 'text_cutter' trys to cut new text if those length was taller than column capacity
> - 'date_normalizer' trys to make date format colums suitable for sql server
> - method='multi' for insert multi row in ine query
> - verbos=True --> show progress bar for your data transfer (default:False)

- and there is some read data methods in order to read data from your database (returns pandas dataframe)

```py
pysql.tables_list(schema=None)
pysql.read_sql_table(table_name, schema=None)
pysql.read_sql_query(query='SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME')
```

- also you can update your table with a update_key and update_value

> this line should update age of someone in the table named Bob Lookie to 83 YO!
> in other way you can set update_key and update_value with list of dicts and it update all queries in a row (len(update_key) should be equal to len(update_value))

```py
pysql.update_table(table_name='personal_data', schema='persons', update_key={'name':'Bob', 'last_name':'Looki'}, update_value={'age':83})
```

- logger is a common method to use ( it logs datetime and process_id and actor_user in order to make your actions trackable )

> every to_sql calls can join with logs with 'process_id' column , so you can find who and when it's started to store data and how long takes it process

```py
pysql.logger('create_connection', 'success', 'connected')
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to advertise your project.